# CSS grid in ie11 with less mixins

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

Did anybody see css grids mixins on less for IE11. 
I try to use grids but it's too difficult write all prefix on IE11. I talk about this:

```
-ms-grid-row: 1;
-ms-grid-column: 3;
-ms-grid-column-span: 2;

grid-column: 3 ~'/' 5;
grid-row: 1;
```

Any lifehacks?

Codepen -> https://codepen.io/Muskos/pen/vpLeJg

Comment: Use Autoprefixer, Luke.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Everybody tried it. It's already about 3 years we don't have to put *any* vendor prefixes into CSS. Just write standard CSS and the tools will do the rest.

Comment: I try to use post css autoprefixer. it doesn't work in ie11

Comment: It's not supposed to work *in* a browser. Consider reading some tutorials on a html/css/javascript preprocess/build tool-chains.

Comment: I understand. And when you add styles after autoprefixer and will see this style in browser. It doesn't work in ie11

Comment: "It doesn't work in ie11" - what exactly you mean here by "It"? Is the CSS you get valid? Does it have `-ms` prefixes after the tool? If it doesn't - check the tool settings, if it does - the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right all you need is:

```
.grid-mixin(@row, @column-start, @column-span, @row-span, @column-end: @column-start + @column-span, @row-end: @row + @row-span){
  -ms-grid-row: @row;
  -ms-grid-row-span: @row-span;
  -ms-grid-column: @column-start;
  -ms-grid-column-span: @column-span;

  grid-column: @column-start ~'/' @column-end;
  grid-row:  @row ~'/' @row-end;
}
```

and when needed you just need to call it like:

```
.grid-mixin(1,3,2,1);
```

You can try this solution here: https://codepen.io/Muskos/pen/vpLeJg?editors=1100

Also if you are using gulp, webpack and etc, use Autoprefixer. It's already about 3 years we don't have to put any vendor prefixes into CSS. Just write standard CSS and the tools will do the rest.

Comment: I try to use it in sass mixin and find mistake:  Undefined variable: "$column-start"

Comment: Oh yhou´re right, when I first wrote it I named the variables a bit different and made a small mistake when changing it, fixed now

Comment: variable @column is undefined

Comment: don't worry. I will fix it, and add @row-end.

Comment: true I failed again, wasn´t paying full attention when answering this sorry. ofc when renaming column to column start you also need to rename it at the bottom ;)